# What is window.constructor and global.constructor native function?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

What is the use of this function? I can't find any information about it.

I've tried in Firefox:

```js
window.constructor()
// TypeError: Illegal constructor

new window.constructor()
// TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

in NodeJS it returns an empty object:

```js
constructor()
// {}
```

For reference if someone what to know why I need to know this:
I have an issue with my Scheme interpreter when I use code like this in NodeJS:

```lisp
(define-class Foo (constructor (lambda (self) (print "<new>"))))
```

The second argument should be the parent object but it's missing. The problem is in NodeJS `constructor()` returns function if you use code like this:

```js
constructor(function foo() { })
// [Function: foo]
```

So my code that checks if the parent is a function will fail in NodeJS.

I'm not sure how to fix my `define-class` but I just want to know what `constructor()` is and if it's documented somewhere.

Comment: @JaromandaX Node and browser both have a `constructor`, it's the same thing. I don't think it has a different meaning depending on the environment.

Comment: Isn't that basically just https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor ? `window` is an object, so it will also have that property, that will refer to the constructor function that created it. That you can't call it, probably has to do with `window` being a "singleton" of sorts? `const o1 = {}; console.log(o1.constructor, o1.constructor(), new o1.constructor())` works fine, doesn't throw any errors - so I guess that indicates `window` is "special".

Comment: @CBroe I just realized that `constructor === Window ` returns true, the same as `window instanceof Window `. But not sure about NodeJS, it acts differently than Browsers.

Comment: @JaromandaX `globalThis` is one object, why would one property be different in NodeJS and browser if both define it? If you have one thing you expect it to behave the same like `globalThis.constructor`.

Comment: @JaromandaX but the window is equivalent to a global object in NodeJS, the code is the same. How it doesn't make sense to ask about the same thing in one question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node and browsers each uses its own implementation of ECMAScript (also known as [the ECMA262 Standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262)), which has no definition for any symbol called `Window`. That *interface* [is defined](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#the-window-object) by *the HTML Standard*, which also doesn't define the `constructor` property.

The *global object* [is defined](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-global-object), however, by ECMA262 (emphasis mine):

> The *global object*:
>
> - is created before control enters any [execution context](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-execution-contexts).
> - does not have a [[Construct]] internal method; it cannot be used as a [constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#constructor) with the **new** operator.
> - does not have a [[Call]] internal method; it cannot be invoked as a function.
> - **has a [[Prototype]] internal slot whose value is [host-defined](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#host-defined)**.
> - may have [host-defined](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#host-defined) properties in addition to the properties defined in this specification. This may include a property whose value is the global object itself.

...where *host-defined* [basically means](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#host) "defined by an external specification or implementation" (such as the HTML Standard or Node).

In other words, `global.constructor`/`window.constructor` is an implementation-dependent detail.

Comment: Or it could be the standard [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Comment: @phuzi Again, it is implementation-dependent, so pretty much anything goes. I guess Node just chose the more lenient way (I don't know about Safari, but Chrome and Firefox both throw `TypeError: Illegal constructor`).